# How to close COM server if client crashes?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have a out-of-proc COM server developed in C++. Client application invokes it using CoCreateInstance. When my client crashes in between, I want my server to close.Is it possible to achieve? I can write a service to monitor both of client and server. But that will require extra deployment overhead for me. Just want to check if there's any built in mechanism in COM.

Comment: If you had written your server component as in-process, you could simple host it in a COM+ Application. A COM+ application can host a .DLL as an out-of-process server w/o any coding required. What's cool with COM+ applications is they are very configurable. For example you can configure it to shutdown automatically when idle. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/com-net/0596001037/ch01s06.html actually, I don't quite understand why developers write out-of-process COM server (unless they have a UI, like Word or Excel)...

Comment: Does the server callback to the client at all? In my COM out-of-proc servers, I keep a list of connected clients, and if communication from server to a client fails, I remove that client from the list and stop communicating with it.

Comment: The OS is supposed to take care of it, automatically terminating servers that have lost their client(s).  It is not something it does quickly, takes at least 10 minutes iirc.  Hard to find the doc page back.